# Changing the value of a cell depending on which cell refers to it

Tags: excel

Value in cell A1 depends on value in cell B, which is a function that is dependent on a number in cell C. I now move to cell A2, which also depends on cell B, however now the number in cell C must be changed by a certain amount. I can change C manually for every next A cell, however this must be done for a large number of A-cells, and the increment of C for every next A-cell is linear. Would there be a method to do this process more efficiently?

I have considered making a list of C values, however the function in B is programmed to only operate on this single cell, and B is later used to calculate the A-cells.

Comment: It might help to understand the question if you post some sample data, and a sample expected output.  Do you know what the C value will be for every cell in column A?

Comment: I know what the C value will be for every next A cell (linear increase by a certain amount). There is only one C cell, and its value must be changed for every next A cell. Reason why I don't have an array of C-cells is because there is already another cell (B) which is a function of C, and the resultant of this function B is used in A. So, for every next A, B should have a different value, as it derives its value from C, which changes for every next A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a quantum computer - you want the B and C cells to simultaneously hold different values depending on which A cell is looking at them?! The only way I can see of doing this is by having A2 refer to B2 which is a function of C2; A3 refers to B3 which is a function of C3 and so on. If the B and C values/functions are defined properly then it should just be a matter of copying A1:C1 down for as many rows as you need.